# Why is my code crashing when I run it in Thread 6: NSOperationQueue?

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = NSURL(string: "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/MYKEYHERE/")
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task: NSURLSessionDownloadTask = session.downloadTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (location: NSURL!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: location)
                let json: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: nil, error: nil) as! NSDictionary!
                println(json)
            }
        })
        task.resume()

    }
```

This is code for a download task to a weather API. Just wondering why I am getting the error:

> Thread 6: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because the response is not JSON (or the JSON is not a dictionary). So, when parsing the JSON, use optional binding to gracefully handle `nil` or non-dictionary errors, perhaps examining the body of response if it fails, e.g.:

```
let task = session.downloadTaskWithURL(url!) { location, response, error in
    if error == nil {
        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: location)
        var error: NSError?
        if let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: nil, error: &error) as? NSDictionary {
            println("json = \(json)")
        } else {
            println("error = \(error)")
            let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            println("not json; responseString = \(responseString)")
            println(response)
        }
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Also, note, when using `JSONObjectWithData`, you not only want to gracefully check for an error, but you generally want to use the `error` parameter, too, as noted above.

BTW, make sure you include the latitude and longitude in the URL as described in the `forecast.io` [API documentation](https://developer.forecast.io/docs/v2), or else you'll get a non-JSON error response. Even if you fix the URL to avoid this error, you should still implement some graceful handling of errors, like above, or else your app might crash whenever there are any server issues.

Comment: Thanks Rob, that's very helpful. But I was just wondering, when you say use the error parameter, I presume you are referring to your optional initalisation of 'var error: NSError?', but why are you doing that? Hasn't the error already been initialised in the completion handler??

Comment: There are two error objects: there's one associated with the network request, but there's also the `error` parameter to `JSONObjectWithData`. I'm worried about the latter. If the network request succeeded (i.e. no `NSError` object is passed to the closure), you still need some variable to hold any error that the JSON parsing generates.